# Dask worker resources for distributed workers

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

When you define worker resources (http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html) in distributed multi-processing workers, is the resource pool defined for all processes?

For example, on the worker host I am running:

```
dask-worker --nprocs 8 --resources HOST=1
```

Now, if I submit task(s) that require `resources={"HOST":1}` does this guarantee that only one of the processes on that machine will execute this task at specific moment in time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resources keyword applies evenly to all processes.  *All* workers will get a single `HOST` resource.  In general for mature deployments on institutional clusters I recommend avoiding the `--nprocs` keyword and instead creating each dask-worker process individually; this is more explicit.

```
dask-worker scheduler-address:8786 --resources
dask-worker scheduler-address:8786
dask-worker scheduler-address:8786
dask-worker scheduler-address:8786
dask-worker scheduler-address:8786
dask-worker scheduler-address:8786
dask-worker scheduler-address:8786
dask-worker scheduler-address:8786
```

Comment: I see.. so in my example what would be the way to make sure that only one of these workers runs particular task? If I still use nprocs and define requirement HOST:1 then all the processes will run concurrently. On the other hand, if I require HOST:8 then... none of them will run?

Same question for separate processes without common nanny.

Comment: Resources don't restrict tasks from running multiple times, they restrict which workers can run which tasks.  The example above, which avoids `--nprocs` should be fully explicit.  I recommend avoiding the `--nprocs` keyword.

Comment: I see, we will move from using --nprocs to using our own process manager and start multiple processes explicitly. 
Let me explain my case a bit more. The idea is that worker processes on a single host still share certain resources. So when I run a task that requires all resources on the host, only one of the workers on this host will be able to run at the same time. I think it's simple with multithreaded worker, but is there a feature supporting this case for multiple worker processes?
PS - we can probably implement some resource sync in our worker code, but it gets more complex

Comment: I recommend using a `dask.utils.SerializableLock`

Comment: When running a task with resource constraint, is the entire task's dependencies also run with the resource constraint, or is the resource constraint applied only on the very last node? In other words, does the resource constraint cascade on the entire computational graph? Is there a way to specify that constraint for only specific part of the graph.

Comment: @MRocklin can you please verify that for syncing between different worker processes we actually need a multi-processing lock (and not `dask.utils.SerializableLock`)?

Also - using this locking approach means that there wont be resource violation, but that the scheduler is unable to make smart choices w.r.t resources rights?

IMO it still isn't clear if there's a best practice to enforce resource use across multiple independent worker processes running on the same physical machine

Comment: SerializableLock only protects within a process.  You may also want to try the `dask.distributed.Lock`.  The scheduler is blind to both.